# create dynamically session value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to create session value according to page title. If I debug the code, The session value does not appear. I can not catch any value. Can somebody help me?

Here is the my code

```
string pageTitle = new PageManager().GetPageNode(new Guid(SiteMapBase.GetCurrentProvider().CurrentNode.Key)).Title;
Session['"' + pageTitle + '"'] == true
```

Comment: how are you storing/creating session value ?

Comment: Have you enabled sessions in `web.config`?

Comment: You don't need to add quotes - > Session['"' + pageTitle + '"'].
Should be like Session[pageTitle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
string pageTitle = new PageManager().GetPageNode(new Guid(SiteMapBase.GetCurrentProvider().CurrentNode.Key)).Title;
Session[pageTitle] = true; //remove double = as it is for comparing, 
                           //also get rid of single quotes
```